# Return value based on AFNetworking response

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm trying to create a function that will return a value based on the response from an AFNetworking POST request.

However, I can't figure out a way to do this, as the function is asynchronous, so the value is returned before the response is actually received.

```
int didLogin;

__block NSString *response;

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];

    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"username":username, @"password":password};

    [manager POST:loginUrl parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        //json "response" object from server response
        response = [responseObject objectForKey:@"response"];

        NSLog(@"Response: %@", response);

        [HUD hide:YES];
        [HUD removeFromSuperViewOnHide];

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        [HUD hide:YES];
        [HUD removeFromSuperViewOnHide];

        NSLog(@"Login Error: %@", error);
    }];

    if ([response compare:@"1"] == NSOrderedSame || [response compare:@"2"] == NSOrderedSame)
    {
        //successful login/1-new device/2-existing device
        didLogin = 1;
    }
    else if ([response compare:@"0"] == NSOrderedSame)
    {
        //unsuccessful login/invalid password
        didLogin = 0;
    }
    else{
        //unsuccessful login
        didLogin = 2;
    }
```

At which point it would return didLogin.

Is there any way to make this work, or do I need to use a synchronous request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method should take a callback block as a parameter and then you should call that block with `didLogin` when the asynchronous process is complete. You need to embrace the asynchronous nature of what you're trying to do throughout your code.

Comment: Took me an hour to figure out how to setup the callback, but I think I got it all working. Thanks!